# Sharepoint 2010 Customizing the Approval Workflow for Change Items

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm trying to use Sharepoint Designer 2010 to create a workflow for a library. We want to have submitters and approvers in the library. Submitters would upload a document, fill out some metadata & the workflow would then start. Approval request would be sent to the approvers. That I can get to work with a basic out of the box approval workflow.

The problem comes in after that. The approvers want to be able to add notes in the metadata of the library item WITHOUT restarting the workflow. Because the workflow history list with rejection comments will erase itself & start over when an edit is made.

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to set it up so that the workflow only restarts when the original library item submitter changes something. Because the assumption would be that if they receive a rejection they would need to edit their submittal & then the process would restart.

Is there a way to do this? I've scoured the internet & attempted to tweak the workflow to no effect. I even attempted to have 2 workflows, one for "start on item creation only" and one for "start on item change only" but the change item only workflow considered the document metadata & initial check in to be a "change" and then I was getting double approval request emails.

We are using SharePoint 2010. Versioning is turned on for this library but check in/check out is not.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a field into the task form for collecting the comments.

Then customize Task action and handle the use cases by adding update current item activity wit task comments

https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Understand-approval-workflows-in-SharePoint-2010-a24bcd14-0e3c-4449-b936-267d6c478579#__toc264526224

Comment: So you're saying that I would need to create a field in the library (metadata) for these comments to be stored and then go back into the workflow and add an "update item on ___" to the tasks?

Comment: You need to add a field in your task form. Then add a field (comment) in your list. Then modify task action and update the current item comment field.

Comment: Ok I have been able to create a field in the task form named "Approver Notes" & have verified that it shows up on the approval form (using infopath). I have also be able to go into the "change behavior of task" and "before task is assigned" set the field. But I'm still having a problem setting it up to copy the information from the approval form into my list.

Comment: The column I created for the task list is called "Approver Notes" I set Task Field Approver Notes = Variable: Approver Notes (which I also created). Then I attempted to set "Update Item in Current Item" using field Approver Notes and Value Variable: Approver Notes. But this does not appear to work.The comments added to Approver Notes are being saved in the column on the task list but they are not being then copied over to the Approver Notes column created in the other list. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.